# Converting Reducer To Tranducer With Ramda

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, reduce, ramda.js, transducer

The following function `reduceIfEven` uses a predicate to check the value the reducer function receives for every step. If the predicate returns true, the value is added to the result (`acc`), otherwise the result is returned from the reducer untouched. Note there is no short-circuiting - all values are processed, either being ignored or added to the result.

```
const isEven = x => x % 2 === 0

const numbers = [
  1,
  2,
  3,
  4,
  5,
  6,
  7
]

const predicateIterator = (predicate, iterator) => (acc, value) =>
  predicate(value) ? iterator(acc, value) : acc;

const reduceIf = curry((predicate, iterator, seed, value) => 
  reduce(predicateIterator(predicate, iterator), seed, value));

const reduceIfEven = reduceIf(isEven, add, 0);

reduceIfEven(numbers); // 12 (2 + 4 + 6)
```

**How can I create a comparable function using [transduce](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#transduce)?**

My initial attempt hit a wall because I need the first function to receive both the result and the value which `map` doesn't.

```
const transducer = compose(filter(isEven), ????(add));
const reduceIfEven = transduce(transducer, R.flip(R.append), []);
```

*Note: this is an academic exercise. I'm just interested in how it can be done, not whether it should be done this way.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the **isOdd** example in the [`transduce()`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#transduce) documentation, you can [`filter()`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#filter) all even,  and [`add()`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#add) them with the accumulator.

```js
const { transduce, add, filter } = R

const numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

const isEven = x => x % 2 === 0

const sumIfEven = transduce(filter(isEven), add, 0)

console.log(sumIfEven(numbers))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```